# 10k tools flags page display problem

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, user-interface, 10k-tools

I think this is due to the recent changes to the formatting of the 10k tools (rather than me upgrading to Firefox 6.0):
[image: screenshot of pretty borders overlapping text on flags page]

(I've grayed out the questions and names to protect the innocent. Obviously, that's not how the page actually appears.)

Comment: *OR MAYBE THAT IS HOW IT APPEARS*

Comment: Why are you shouting, @Jeff? (If that was meant as a joke, it's whooshing somewhere way above my head.)

Comment: @Jeff ahah that made me laugh. lol

Comment: i'm looking into this now

Comment: It is same for other users below 10k.

Comment: @Sonic: Where? You don't see the same flag page, so where else is the alignment off?

Comment: @sim alignment is off somewhere else.

Comment: @Sonic: Yes, I understand that. When the devs check this, it might be extremely helpful for them to know *where* "somewhere else" is.

Comment: @simchona: I think he refers to [this one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/strange-slide-bug). :D

Comment: This is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not an answer but I got the same problem too, although on just one of the flags, the other two are fine. I'm using Chrome.

[image]

Comment: That's very strange: why is the decorative bit only showing on the last item? Did the page perhaps fail to load completely?

Comment: Actually, before now, I never saw the decorative thing. They always appeared without it... And to me it seemed the page was loaded.

Comment: The decorative thing is added when showing the user who asked the question; as you see, in the first three cases, it is reported who answered, not who asked. This means that in the first three cases, the flag was for an answer, while in the latter case, a question was flagged.

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't exist anymore as this part of the 10k tools has been moved to the review queue since then.